# MS Planner - change Plan icon after rename

Tags: office365

In MS Planner (part of Office 365), the *Plan* is like a 'board' in other systems (e.g. Trello).  Say we have a *Plan* where its original name was `Admin Tasks`.  Then we later rename it `DBA Projects`.  When the *Plan* is first created, its default 'icon' is the *Plan*'s title initials, `AT`, with some flat background color.

The **problem** is, after the rename, the *Plan*'s (default) icon will **not** automatically change.  Being a stickler, this is really bothering me.  How can I change the *Plan*'s icon and make it use the new title initials, `DP`?

Answer (score 2):

Some searching brought me to an MS Answers post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_win10/office-365-planner-cant-change-the-plan-name-and/cda2ba60-3e42-4215-93be-70777c5c3ba0).  To change the Plan's icon, which is really a Group in O365, you go to the People app and edit the icon there.  I uploaded a "custom" icon (just a random jpg/png), Saved it.  Then came back to edit it again, *removed* the custom picture, and Saved again.  Finally, I cleared my browser's cached images, and *viola*, the Plan's icon was showing its new title initials in the Planner app.  Yay!  Pictures shown.

[image: find the group in People and edit the icon]

[image: upload new img with the pencil, save, come back, trash it with the trashcan]